# Controlling motion's threshold automatically on my PI

Tags: cron, motion

I have **Motion** installed on my PI and having difficulty trying to control the threshold via the command line.

Motion's [wiki](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/RemoteControlHttp) suggests that this type of control can be done using cron like this:

```
`0 9 * * * root /usr/bin/lwp-request http://localhost:8080/0/detection/start > /dev/null`
```

So i tried this on the command line:

```
 /usr/bin/wget http://localhost:8091/0/config/set?threshold=4000 > /dev/null
```

and goth this:

```
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1, ::1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8091... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.
```

I tried this on my laptop's browser connected to the same network:

```
  http://192.168.1.51:8091/0/config/set?threshold=2000&username=myusername&password=mypassword
```

and it appeared to work without having to enter my username and password manually.

so i then tried on the command line:

```
sudo /usr/bin/wget http://192.168.1.51:8091/0/config/set?threshold=4000&username=myusername&password=mypassword >/dev/null
```

and got :

```
Connecting to 192.168.1.51:8091... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 401 Authorization Required
Authorization failed.

[1]-  Exit 6                  sudo /usr/bin/wget http://192.168.1.51:8091/0/config/set?threshold=4000
[2]+  Done                    username=myusername
```

1) Did this not work because of having [control_authentication](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/ConfigOptionControlAuthentication) set up?

2) Is it possible to control motion in this way with authentication set up if so how?

3) Am I approaching this in the correct way?

Comment: I don't have proper motion experience (not for years), but both A) and C) look feasible to me. I think the easiest way to figure it out would be to try!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to control motion using the software interface and wrote a rough script:

[script to control motion using cron](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14486/control-motion-via-cron/15596#15596)